# RSpec: Is there a setting to have js: true for all the specs?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, rspec, capybara

Whenever a request spec fails, I use `respec` gem to rerun failed examples. When doing this, I want to activate `:chrome` as driver (instead of headless `:webkit`) so I can inspect the problem visually within Chrome.

Instead of adding a `driver: :chrome` manually to the test case, I'd like to specify it globally like so:

# spec_helper.rb
  Capybara.javascript_driver = if defined?(Respec)
                                     :chrome # Use headed browser to inspect stuff visually when respec'ing
                                   else
                                     :webkit # Otherwise use headless browser
                                   end

Sadly this doesn't seem to work for specs that don't have JavaScript enabled. Is there a way to switch JS on for all specs? Something like:

```
# spec_helper.rb
Capybara.javascript_driver = if defined?(Respec)
                                   Capybara.javascript = true
                                   :chrome # Use headed browser to inspect stuff visually when respec'ing
                                 else
                                   :webkit # Otherwise use headless browser
                                 end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`javascript_driver` is used [only for scenarios with `@javascript` tag](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/cucumber.rb#L17).

You should modify `default_driver` instead of `javascript_driver` if you want to run all scenarios with chrome:

```
if defined?(Respec)
  Capybara.default_driver = :chrome
else
  Capybara.default_driver = :webkit
  Capybara.javascript_driver = :chrome
end
```